# How to make bullet like projectile motion?

Tags: python, pygame

Currently I try this make shooting game based on the link I have found. But there is I want to change the bullet properties but I didn't know about physics and code it. I want make the bullet move in projectile motion. Can someone help me to code it.

this is some of the code:

```
man = player(200, 410, 64, 64)
bullets = []
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(27)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    for bullet in bullets:
        if bullet.x < 500 and bullet.x > 0:
            bullet.x += bullet.vel
        else:
            bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
```

[Full Source code is here](https://techwithtim.net/tutorials/game-development-with-python/pygame-tutorial/projectiles/)

Comment: What does "move in projectile motion" even mean? Do you mean bullet drop? If yes, then what you need to implement is gravity in the y-direction of the bullet vector. Essentially, your bullet position can be described as a function of time as a (x,y) vector. So something like: ```def bullet_position(x0,y0,t,vx0,vy0): return (x0+vx0*t,y0+vy0*t-1/2*g*t**2)``` where g is the gravitational constant, x0, y0 are the starting coordinates and vx0 and vy0 are the initial velocities in x and y direction.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion

Answer (score 0):

Essentially Projectile Motion means there are two forces acting on the projectile - there is the initial velocity (in some direction), and gravity.  As the projectile moves through space and time, its trajectory (the path it moves) can be calculated by applying the velocity, gravity and time.

I'm not going to go into the formulae here, just use them.  Read the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion) on Projectile Motion for explanations.  Basically to move a projectile we just need to calculate it's [displacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion#Displacement).  Essentially you can handle the movement of the object as if it has separate horizontal and vertical changes.

So, let's make a simple sprite object that moves with projectile motion.  We will use the PyGame sprite class for simplicity (and the whole-whack of pre-existing library code it provides).

So, we need an image, xy-position, a start angle and velocity.

```
class Projectile( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    GRAVITY          = -9.8  # Earth

    def __init__( self, bitmap, start_x, start_y, velocity=0, angle=0 ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self )
        self.image       = bitmap
        self.rect        = bitmap.get_rect()
        self.start_x     = start_x
        self.start_y     = start_y
        self.rect.center = ( ( start_x, start_y ) )
        # Physics
        self.start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()   # "now" in milliseconds
        self.velocity   = velocity
        self.angle      = math.radians( angle )     # Note: convert Degrees to Radians
```

And that's it.  We can create a Projectile  like:

```
rock = Projectile( rock_image, 10, 100, 50, 60 )
```

Giving a Projectile, drawn as a "rock_image", starting at (10, 100), with a velocity of 50, and an angle of 60 degrees.

> One thing to note, is that angles in mathematics libraries are usually specified in [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) (not degrees).  I can't think in radians, so I use degrees outside the class.  It's your code, write it the way you want though.

The velocity is a bit weird, since typically you do these sorts of calculations in metres per second, and here it's pixels per millisecond, but I don't want to go into that, because it's an unimportant digression, and is scaled away with a single number.

So now we need to add the movement.  Movement of a PyGame sprite is handled by the `update()` function.  So we need to write this function such that for any given time in the future, it's possible to work out the `x` and `y` co-ordinates of where to draw the "rock_image".  So quoting [wikipedia's formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion#Displacement):

> x = start_velocity * time_now * cos( start_angle )
>   y = start_velocity * time_now * sin( start_angle ) - ½ * gravity * time_now²

This gives us the `Projectile.update()` function:

```
def update( self ):
    time_now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if ( self.velocity > 0 ):
        time_change = ( time_now - self.start_time )
        if ( time_change > 0 ):
            time_change /= 100.0  # fudge for metres/second to pixels/millisecond
            # re-calculate the displacement
            # x
            displacement_x  = self.velocity * time_change * math.sin( self.angle )
            # y
            half_gravity_time_squared = self.GRAVITY * time_change * time_change / 2.0
            displacement_y  = self.velocity * time_change * math.cos( self.angle ) + half_gravity_time_squared

            # reposition sprite (subtract y, because in pygame 0 is screen-top)
            self.rect.center = ( ( self.start_x + int( displacement_x ), self.start_y - int( displacement_y ) ) )
```

Obviously this needs to be updated to only update the sprite if it's still on-screen, etc.  We also differ slightly from the textbook calculations, because in PyGame positive-Y is *down* the screen (whereas generally positive-Y is *up*).

So putting all this together, here's a short demo that creates 20 Projectiles at the centre-bottom of the screen, pointing somewhat up, with a random velocity:

```
import pygame
import random
import math

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH  = 800
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400
FPS           = 60

# background colours
INKY_GREY    = ( 128, 128, 128 )

INITIAL_VELOCITY_LOW  = 10  # pixels per millisecond (adjusted later)
INITIAL_VELOCITY_HIGH = 100
LAUNCH_ANGLE          = 80  # random start-angle range

class Projectile( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    GRAVITY          = -9.8  

    def __init__( self, bitmap, start_x, start_y, velocity=0, angle=0 ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self )
        self.image       = bitmap
        self.rect        = bitmap.get_rect()
        self.start_x     = start_x
        self.start_y     = start_y
        self.rect.center = ( ( start_x, start_y ) )
        # Physics
        self.start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()   # "now" in milliseconds
        self.velocity   = velocity
        self.angle      = math.radians( angle )     # Note: convert Degrees to Radians            

    def update( self ):
        time_now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if ( self.velocity > 0 and self.rect.y < WINDOW_HEIGHT - self.rect.height ):
            time_change = ( time_now - self.start_time ) 
            if ( time_change > 0 ):
                time_change /= 100.0  # fudge for metres/second to pixels/millisecond
                # re-calculate the displacement
                # x
                displacement_x  = self.velocity * time_change * math.sin( self.angle ) 
                # y
                half_gravity_time_squared = self.GRAVITY * time_change * time_change / 2.0
                displacement_y  = self.velocity * time_change * math.cos( self.angle ) + half_gravity_time_squared 

                # reposition sprite
                self.rect.center = ( ( self.start_x + int( displacement_x ), self.start_y - int( displacement_y ) ) )

                # Stop at the bottom of the window
                if ( self.rect.y >= WINDOW_HEIGHT - self.rect.height ):
                    self.rect.y = WINDOW_HEIGHT - self.rect.height
                    self.velocity = 0
                    self.kill()   # remove the sprite


### MAIN
pygame.init()
SURFACE = pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF | pygame.RESIZABLE
window  = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), SURFACE )
pygame.display.set_caption("Projectile Motion Example")

# Load resource image(s)
sprite_image = pygame.image.load( "ball.png" )#.convert_alpha()

# Make some sprites 
screen_centre_x = WINDOW_WIDTH  // 2
screen_bottom_y = WINDOW_HEIGHT - 10
SPRITES = pygame.sprite.Group()   
for i in range( 20 ):
    speed = random.randrange( INITIAL_VELOCITY_LOW, INITIAL_VELOCITY_HIGH )  # metres per second
    angle = random.randrange( -LAUNCH_ANGLE, LAUNCH_ANGLE ) 
    new_sprite = Projectile( sprite_image, screen_centre_x, screen_bottom_y, speed, angle )
    SPRITES.add( new_sprite )

# Main Loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done  = False
while not done:
    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True

    # Repaint the screen
    window.fill( INKY_GREY )
    SPRITES.update()          # re-position the sprites
    SPRITES.draw( window )    # draw the sprites

    # Update the window, but not more than 60fps
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick_busy_loop( FPS )

pygame.quit()
```

And the ball.png:  [image: ball.png]

Style Note: I *always* put brackets around if conditions.  This is in violation of PEP8, but I think it makes the code more readable.